# Error importing org.apache.batik

Tags: java, apache, batik

I'm trying to use the Java-based toolkit **Batik**. 
I have downloaded **Apache Batik 1.8** and edited the environmental variable *Path* to include the path where I put its files (*C:\Program Files\Batik\batik-1.8*). 
In a Java file that I want to compile, the following imports are present.

```
import org.apache.batik.svggen.SVGGraphics2D;
import org.apache.batik.dom.GenericDOMImplementation;
```

And when I try compiling this, the following errors occurs.

```
error: package org.apache.batik.svggen does not exist
error: package org.apache.batik.dom does not exist
```

What have I missed?

Comment: The jars have to be in the _Classpath_ .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
The jars have to be in the Classpath.
```

This solved the problem.